# Mgt-toolkit get with HTML-attribute data-for doest work with React?

Tags: reactjs, graph, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to display the values of response, but React doest support the data-for HTML-attribute. When i use the template from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/get I get the error: unexpected variable email. See my implementation below. I can't use `{{email.subject}}` in this case.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useDebugValue } from 'react';
import { Get } from '@microsoft/mgt-react';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

function GetMessage() {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
    const value = <Get></Get>;
    console.log(value);

    return (
        isAuthenticated && (
            <mgt-get resource="/me/messages" version="beta" scopes="mail.read" max-pages="2">
                <template>
                    <div class="email" data-for="email in value">
                        <h3>{{ email.subject }}</h3>
                        <h4>
                            <mgt-person person-query="{{email.sender.emailAddress.address}}" view="oneline" person-card="hover"></mgt-person>
                        </h4>
                        <div data-if="email.bodyPreview" class="preview" innerHtml>{{email.bodyPreview}}</div>
                        <div data-else class="preview">email body is empty</div>
                    </div>
                </template>
                <template data-type="loading">loading</template>
                <template data-type="error">{{ this }}</template>
            </mgt-get>
        )
    )
}

export default GetMessage;
```

I tried to use the mgt-toolkit examples. The other components works fine.

Comment: As you said other components works fine , which component you are talking about ? have you got any information related to signed user ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/get),React Toolkit do support the data -for HTML-attribute.
In the code you provided above, the error says unable to find the variable mail ,I am wondering you are using authenticating through AuthO,you are using && operation ,might be there is any issue with authentication please confirm once or you can also try to [login with React Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/login) , you can also check in the [React Toolkit playground](https://mgt.dev/?path=/story/components-mgt-get--get-email&source=docs), this is working as expected.

[image]

Hope this helps,

If you still having the issue , kindly share the screenshot of output as well ,to understand where it fails

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using Auth0 identity provide with Microsoft connection. It works fine with for example  and . The response of  returns all the emails correctly, but I React doesnt support data-for HTML attribute. The error says: "unexpected token email". See the attachments.

[as you can see the  tag returns and displays the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8EyT.png)

[This is the response of . The response is correct, but I cant loop and display for example "bodyPreview."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y27NY.png)

[This shows my implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52iAg.png)

Is there a different approach to display the response? So how can I display the value without data-for attribute?

Thanks for your response and support!